# How to allow users to share videos on my website securely

Tags: security, node.js, couchdb, express

Just finished an awesome book on Web App Security, and I've got a security question. I'd like to allow users to share videos on my website. I don't have a problem restricting them to youtube and vimeo embedding, saves me the storage anyways, but I don't want untrusted code running on site.

So, what's the best way to do this?

FYI, I'm using express.js on top of node.js and couchdb for a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What untrusted code are you referring to? You can store references to external videos in your database, and just use them to embed a player in your views. No code from Youtube or Vimeo needs to run on your server to accomplish this. The Youtube API also enables you to allow users to upload videos directly to Youtube from the browser, without proxying through your webserver. This means users can upload and embed youtube videos without any 3rd party code on the server side of your application.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading#Browser_based_uploading

To create your links from a video id, you could simply use:

```
var directLink = "http://youtube.com/watch?v={0}".format(videoId);
var embedLink = "http://youtube.com/embed/watch?v={0}".format(videoId);
var shortLink = "http://youtu.be/watch?v={0}".format(videoId);
```

Comment: Storing references is exactly the approach I was hoping to take, but how to deal with references is unclear to me. There's the url to the page where the youtube video lives http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdGLZPyPCkA, then there's url within the embed code http://www.youtube.com/embed/LdGLZPyPCkA, and then there's even the shortened url under the share option http://youtu.be/LdGLZPyPCkA. So, do how to I write code that knows how to deal with each of these links?

Comment: Notice the common element for all of those links. All you have to store is LdGLZPyPCkA and when your view is being generated, you build the rest of the URL depending on how it is being used.

Comment: Genius! You rock! Hmm...so the Regex expression to grab that is going to be a bit tricky. Grab the last 11 characters would work, except sometimes there are other query params after the video id. Hmmm... let's search google for how others do this. Thanks so much Timothy!!